# PowerShell hash table or array for comparing strings

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find the frequency of folder names split across unique directories from a text file of the path names. So using this dataset I want the following results:

1. Data

   - C:\Project_1\Models\MapShedMaps\randomfilename.txt
   - C:\Project_1\Models\MapShedMaps\randomfilename.txt
   - C:\Project_1\Models\MapShedMaps\randomfilename.txt
   - C:\Project_2\Models\MapShedMaps\randomfilename.txt
   - C:\Project_3\Models\MapShedMaps\randomfilename.txt
   - C:\Project_3\Models\MapShedMaps\randomfilename.txt
   - C:\Project_3\Models\MapShedMaps\randomfilename.txt
2. Results

   - Project_1 = 1
   - Project_2 = 1
   - Project_3 = 1
   - Models = 3
   - MapShedMaps = 3

My first idea for this would be to use Get-Content and then ForEach-Object to split each word out from the path and store them in a hash table that keeps count. In order to stop the duplicating, I was thinking of an array or another hash table to store the currnet object's path up that point... It all falls apart there. I am not sure what the best approach to storing the "parent" members of a path are in order to know if it's a unique occurance. Any suggestiosn on how to do this would be great.

UPDATE:

OK, I am thinking something like a hash table $SAVE and counts each unqiue value, an array $PREVIOUS that is the last object from the pipe, and an array $HAVESEEN that's a capture of the pipe from the start.

SO the first object would be C if the string is broken, next is Project_1 and C is moved to $PREVIOUS and $HAVESEEN. I am going to try and write this up, I am not sure how passing all this between the hash table and arrays will work though.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you can get the first 3 result items by grouping the paths then compute the other values:

```
PS> Get-Content .\file.txt | Group-Object -NoElement

Count Name
----- ----
    3 C:\Project_1\Models\MapShedMaps\randomfilename.txt
    1 C:\Project_2\Models\MapShedMaps\randomfilename.txt
    3 C:\Project_3\Models\MapShedMaps\randomfilename.txt
```

Comment: Going straing from the file system isn't going to be possible. It's multiple network drives and over 10 million directories at least. parsing a word file seems more likely.

Comment: You can get a list of directories and dump them to a file, pipe to select-object or sort-object and specify the -Unique switch do remove duplicates and then try the above.

Comment: You're going to have to expand on that, I am not going to know the unique switch, it's millions of directories.

Comment: After you exported all paths to a file you read it and discard duplicates with: 'get-content paths.txt | select -unique', or with sort: 'get-content paths.txt | sort -unique'. Then you can pipe to group object.